# Matrix Multiplication using Templates in c++

Tags: c++, function, templates, matrix

I am trying to use class templates to matrices. But I have run into a problem with matrix multiplication.

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<Matrix<T, N, M>, T, N, M> {

    template<unsigned int K>
    friend Matrix<T, N, K> operator*(const Matrix<T, N, M>& m1, const Matrix<T, M, K>& m2) {
        Matrix<T, N, K> ret;
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n != N; n++) {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k != K; k++) {
                ret.i[n][k] = 0;
                for (unsigned int m = 0; m != M; m++) {
                    ret.i[n][k] += m1.i[n][m]*m2.i[m][k];
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

When it then comes to multiplying two mat4's(4x4 matrices), like so:

```
m_model = (m_view*m_model);
```

It gives the error `Invalid operands to binary expression ('mat4' (aka 'Matrix<float, 4, 4>') and 'mat4')`. Having had a look online I can see this is not the intended use of function templates, as you have to assign on call the template arguments. Is there a way around this similar to what I first intended, i.e. automatic assignment of the template argument based on the second argument of the function?

Here are the definitions of MatrixBase and Matrix(aka mat4) respectively:

MatrixBase

```
template<typename T , unsigned int M>
struct ComponentColumn{
    T& operator[](int m) {
        return i[m];
    }

    const T& operator[](int m) const {
        return i[m];
    }


    T i[M];
};


//-----------MATRIXBASE-----------
template <typename ChildT, typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class MatrixBase {
public:
    MatrixBase() {}

    MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M> operator*=(const MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M>& m1) {
        MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M> ret;
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n != N; n++) {
            for (int k = 0; k != M; k++) {
                ret.i[n][k] = 0;
                for (unsigned int m = 0; m != M; m++) {
                    ret.i[n][k] += (*this).i[n][m]*m1.i[m][k];
                }
            }
        }

        *this = ret;

        return ret;
    }

    MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M> operator+(const MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M>& m1) {
        MatrixBase<ChildT, T, N, M> ret;
        for (int n = 0; n != N; n++) {
            for (int m = 0; m != M; m++) {
                ret.i[n][m] = i[n][m];
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    ComponentColumn<T, M>& operator[](int n) {
        return this->i[n];
    }


    const ComponentColumn<T, M>& operator[](int n) const {
        return this->i[n];
    }

    explicit operator T*() {
        return &(*this)[0][0];
    }

protected:
    ComponentColumn<T, M> i[N];
};
```

mat4

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix<T, 4, 4> : public MatrixBase<Matrix<T, 4, 4>, T, 4, 4> {
public:
    Matrix<T, 4, 4>() {
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n != 4; n++) {
            for (unsigned int m = 0; m != 4; m++) {
                if (n == m) {
                    (*this)[n][m] = 1;
                } else {
                    (*this)[n][m] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Matrix<T, 4, 4>(const Matrix<T, 3, 3>& m) {
        (*this)[0][0] = m[0][0]; (*this)[1][0] = m[1][0]; (*this)[2][0] = m[2][0]; (*this)[3][0] = 0;
        (*this)[0][1] = m[0][1]; (*this)[1][1] = m[1][1]; (*this)[2][1] = m[2][1]; (*this)[3][1] = 0;
        (*this)[0][2] = m[0][2]; (*this)[1][2] = m[1][2]; (*this)[2][2] = m[2][2]; (*this)[3][2] = 0;
        (*this)[0][3] = 0; (*this)[1][3] = 0; (*this)[2][3] = 0; (*this)[3][3] = 1;
    }

    static Matrix<T, 4, 4> Translate(T x, T y, T z);
    static Matrix<T, 4, 4> Translate(const vec3& v);
    static Matrix<T, 4, 4> Scale(T s);
    static Matrix<T, 4, 4> Rotate(T degrees);
    static Matrix<T, 4, 4> Frustum(T left, T right, T bottom, T top, T near, T far);

    explicit operator Matrix<T, 3, 3>() {
        Matrix<T, 3, 3> ret;
        for (int n = 0; n != 3; n++) {
            for (int m = 0; m != 3; m++) {
                ret[n][m] = (*this)[n][m];
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    Matrix<T, 4, 4> Transpose() {
        Matrix<T, 4, 4> ret = Matrix<T, 4, 4>();
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n != 4; n++) {
            for (unsigned int m = 0; m != 4; m++) {
                ret.i[n][m] = this->i[m][n];
            }
        }
        *this = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    Matrix<T, 4, 4> Inverse();
};
```

Comment: You might consider using a library to do this so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Try Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/)

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://ideone.com/oNn4mI).

Comment: Worked for me too, without that MatrixBase, but defining `array<array<T, N>, M> i;` in the Matrix class.

Comment: Ok, that's worrying. But I do have another template for the mat4 class definition, might be the problem. Although I got the same error when this function was a part of the MatrixBase class.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing this for practice, which would be a good exercise, I would just use an existing linear algebra library which implements matrix vector operations. Such as Armadillo: http://arma.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I think you are probably right. It is a shame though, I have my Maths "Library" pretty entrenched. I am think of going with GLM, it is specific to OpenGL and is written in c++, can't think of a reason not to use it.

Comment: Break free of that entrenchment! Refactor your library so that you can provide adaptors for specific operations: *, ^, %, etc... 

The fruits of your labour will be overwhelming. Imagine allowing your client code to implement GPU matrix multiplication simply by providing a template specialization which calls an external library *hint hint ArrayFire or Armadillo*.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but to share what worked for me and assure the correctness of the method of defining the multiplication operator:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class Matrix {
public:
  template<unsigned int K>
  friend Matrix<T, N, K> operator*(const Matrix<T, N, M>& m1, const Matrix<T, M, K>& m2) {
    Matrix<T, N, K> ret;
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n != N; n++) {
      for (unsigned int k = 0; k != K; k++) {
        ret.i[n][k] = 0;
        for (unsigned int m = 0; m != M; m++) {
          ret.i[n][k] += m1.i[n][m] * m2.i[m][k];
        }
      }
    }
    return ret;
  }
  array<array<T, M>, N> i;
};

int main() {
  Matrix<float, 4, 6> m1; Matrix<float, 6, 10> m2;
  auto m3 = (m1 * m2);
  cout << m3.i[0][0] << m3.i[3][9] << "\n";
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Well I have got it to work for me with everything but mat4's. It is the definition of mat4 that overrides the general template class. The problem lies with using MatrixBase to define Vector as well. MatrixBase takes ChildT in the template, which is the class that inherits MatrixBase. So I think it is evident that it is hard to define the multiplication in MatrixBase, because the ChildT can't be redefined for the new Matrix with different order.

Comment: @James: And why haven't you posted `mat4`'s definition?

Comment: @Cornstalks I didn't think it was relevant, except to say it doesn't define a * operator. As you can see from above I am now switching to the glm library. But in case it helps someone else I shall edit my question to include MatrixBase and mat4.

Comment: @James: Well, it turns out it's actually *very* relevant, because you've specialized the class (and that's what's causing the error). Specializations share nothing with their non-specialized version (they're a different class), which means that `Matrix<T, 4, 4>` has no `operator*` because you didn't declare/define on in the specialization. This is why StackOverflow makes a big deal about [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because these little details often are quite important, and unless there's a *complete* example, we can't help a whole lot.

Comment: @Cornstalks even if it was a simple typedef, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: @A.S.H: Well, if it was a typedef instead of a specialization, it would still have an `operator*`, but yes, it would still be an important detail to put in the question (as the example wouldn't be complete without it).

Comment: @Cornstalks I was afraid this would be the case. I just don't have a fix for it. But I am using the glm library now, not plain sailing but probability for the best. However, if I were to fix the problem I think I might separate MatrixBase from Vector(I had vectors defined as column matrices), even though it would be a shame to lose the nice mathematically sound definition.